# Images in radiobutton list

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, radiobuttonlist

I have a page where people need to make selections from a radio button list.
I read a variation of this on adding images to a check box list, but it didn't work for me.
Essentially, I have a data source in my DAL(data access layer) and I'm calling it to drive my radio button list - and when I add my images to it, I only get one image to show up (depending on how I do it, the same image shows up every time).

Here's my code: (why can't I get it to show ALL the images?)

```
using (MyDataConnection db = new MyDataConnection())
{
    var dt = db.LogoSelectionTableCollection.GetAllAsDataTable();

    foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
    {
        //get values
        drow["LogoName"] = dt.Rows[0]["LogoName"].ToString();
        drow["LogoValue"] = dt.Rows[0]["LogoValue"].ToString();

        //assign values
        var dtVal = drow["LogoValue"].ToString();
        var dtName = drow["LogoName"].ToString();

        //filename and file path
        var fileName = dtVal.Replace(".pdf", ".jpg");
        var filePath = "/imageUrl/TempImg/" + fileName;

        //add to radio button list
        rdbtnlistLogoSelect.Items.Add(
            new ListItem(
            string.Format(
                "<img src='{0}' alt='" + dtName +
                "' width='38px' style='padding-left:4px; padding-right:4px;' align='middle' /><br />" +
                dtName + "", filePath), dtVal));
    }
}
```

So, why doesn't it work?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate question : [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1316774.aspx/1)

Comment: Sort of, yes... and I think it may be helpful, I will try it and see.  Thanks!

Comment: I kind of went another route with it (combining both), and it worked.  Thank you for your suggestion.